# Why am I seeing these thread messages in my output window?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I'm watching my output window in a default MVC 5 project (VS2013) and am noticing some messages.  What is going on? I didn't add any threading to my app.

```
The thread 0x7dc0 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x25b8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x7418 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x13a8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just debugging message. You can switch that off by right clicking into the output window and uncheck the thread ended message.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs4c1wda.aspx

```
In addition to program out from your application, the Output window can display the information about:

Modules the debugger has loaded or unloaded.

Exceptions that are thrown.

Processes that exit.

Threads that exit.
```

an application may have a lot of threads running in parallel. Some are run by you, the coder, some are run by framework classes. These could also come from any libraries that you have in your project. I get the same in my output window on the current project I'm working on... this doesn't bother me.